# Deprecated message when adding MIME extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mime-types

I've added the following into `initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
text_plain = MIME::Types["application/octet-stream"].first
text_plain.extensions << "fmf"
MIME::Types.index_extensions text_plain`
```

This works with Paperclip but I get the following message when running rspec:

```
MIME::Types#index_extensions is deprecated and will be private.
```

Are there any other methods of adding a new extension without using the above deprecated method?

Answer (score 3):

According to the thread at [Thoughtbot Paperclip Issue #1737](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1737), you may be able to use the following pattern to avoid the deprecation warning.

```
text_plain = MIME::Types["application/octet-stream"].first
text_plain.add_extensions "fmf"
```

Sorry this answer may not be helpful a year later, but perhaps someone else will find it useful.